# #1064 - SQL syntax Error. near 'json DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=INNODB' at line 4

Tags: json, xampp, mariadb

Help. Can't figure out the issue with this MYSQL create table statement.   My XXAMP version are:

**ApacheFriends XAMPP Version 1.8.2

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for Win32 (x86)

PHP 5.4.22 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2013 21:17:59)

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32)**

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
      `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The error is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=INNODB' at line 4

Comment: If you're running MySQL 5.5.34 then it doesn't have the JSON data type, this was introduced in MySQL 5.7.8.

Comment: Well I haven't updated XXAMP in a while. I'll check thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct @lasse-v-karlsen

the solution was I wass running MySQL 5.5.34 which doesn't support the JSON data type.

I upgraded MYSQL to the latest version and the statement ran with no issues.